# c# GetElementsByTagName then read the inner tags values how

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, tags, getelementsbytagname

this below is example xml

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO>WSJ870323-0180</DOCNO>
<HL>Italy's Commercial Vehicle Sales</HL>
<DD>03/23/87</DD>
<DATELINE>TURIN, Italy</DATELINE>
<TEXT>Commercial-vehicle sales in Italy rose 11.4% in February from a year earlier, to 8,848 units, according to provisional figures from the Italian Association of Auto Makers.</TEXT>
</DOC>

<DOC>
<DOCNO>WSJ870323-0180</DOCNO>
<HL>Italy's Commercial Vehicle Sales</HL>
<DD>03/23/87</DD>
<DATELINE>TURIN, Italy</DATELINE>
<TEXT>Commercial-vehicle sales in Italy rose 11.4% in February from a year earlier, to 8,848 units, according to provisional figures from the Italian Association of Auto Makers.</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

and this below code is not working why ?

```
       System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("docs.xml");

    XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DOC");
    for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
    {
        string docno = elemList[i].Attributes["DOCNO"].ToString();
    }
```

C# 4.0 wpf

Comment: Is the XML sample that you posted part of a single document? If yes, you should enclose them inside of a root element. In this case, your root is <DOC> and it repeats multiple times.

Comment: `DOCNO` is not attribute. It is sub-element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Linq To Xml to parse Xml is much more easier. For example,

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("docs.xml");

var docs = xDoc.Descendants("DOC")
            .Select(x => new{
                DocNo = x.Element("DOCNO").Value,
                Text = x.Element("TEXT").Value
            })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this code, assuming you have a valid root:

```
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DOC");
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    var elements = elemList[i].SelectNodes("DOCNO");
    if (elements == null || elements.Count == 0) continue;
    var firstElement = elements.Item(0);
    var docno = firstElement.InnerText;
}
```